# CMake execute_process execute script which uses input and output

Tags: input, cmake, output

If I call Python/Bash script from CMake using execute_process and this script uses input/output, it doesn't work - can't get any input or display output when script executes. Is there any way to do it? I need to continue building my project differently depending on user input.
Example CMakeLists.txt

```
execute_process(
  COMMAND python ${MY_BUILD_DIR}/test_input.py
)
```

Example test_input.py

```
result = raw_input("Enter something + [ENTER]: ")
print(result)
```

Edit:
Actually, if this script is called as only COMMAND in execute_process (as in my example) then Python waits for input normally except that no output is printed ("Enter something + [ENTER]: "). If I use another COMMAND and similar Python (or Bash) script then raw_input will return output ("Enter something + [ENTER]: " + result) from first script (which is as described in execute_process) but subsequent raw_input calls would fail "EOFError: EOF when reading a line" as if input was read from file and EOF is received but I expected to read next line from standard input.

So I have two problems:

1. Can't display anything during execution of script through execute_process.
2. Can't read standard input normally in subsequent scripts.

Comment: could you provide a minimal example?

Comment: Is this input likely to be fixed for each build configuration or vary with each build?  Can you get the input through the CMake configuration step and inject it into the script?

Comment: It would be enough to get "Press [ENTER] to continue..." working.